# Box2d - How to make a conveyor belt

Tags: flash, box2d

Here:
[flash game](http://www.fupa.com/play/Action-free-games/garbage-separator.html)

There is a flash game called garbage separator. In this game, there is a conveyor belt. 
With 2 Circles you can move the conveyor, and i think you can use boxes with joint for belt but i dont know how to give it the form:

[Circular Form](http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/imagen/previo/thump_6040126belt.gif)

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this with Box2d? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "but i dont know how to give it the form" and with the picture you provided. Could you elaborate or rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the belt you'll need to specify the points of each section of the belt. i.e. the boxes. To get the 'form' I'd suspect you would just have to angle the sections around each of the sides which should be easy enough. Depending on the size of the circle and the width of each 'box' youll be able to determine how many 'box's are needed to get around the circle.